# Javascript - window.getComputedStyle returns "auto" as element top and left properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my webpage, I've got elements (divs, sub divs, buttons etc.) whose position is generated relative to the div they're in and to each other. This has the result that when using **window.getComputedStyle**, the *top* and *left* property are no number values, but simply "auto" while *width* and *height* are in px.

The problem that I need the absolute values for measuring purposes so I was wondering if there's a way to get them somehow. I was hoping **window.getComputedStyle** would do, but obviously it doesn't.

There's an example below, without any formatting but the same problem.

If there's a jQuery solution, I'd of course appreciate it as well.

Kind regards,
jaySon

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
      var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]);
      alert(
        "top = " + style.top + //auto
        "\nleft = " + style.left + //auto
        "\nwidth = " + style.width + //63px
        "\nheight = " + style.height //24px
      );
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button id="buttonTest" onClick="test()">Test it!</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The getComputedStyle method returns the [resolved value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolved_value) of CSS properties.

If the style sheet author(you) did not specify values for certain CSS properties(ie: top, right, bottom, and left) then the resolved value returned will be the default value. These CSS properties all have a default value of "auto".

If you cannot or don't want to specify a value yourself in the stylesheet and you only need coordinates relative to the top-left of the viewport, consider using [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        /* Remove default styling to ensure a top and left value of 0 */
        body {margin:0; padding:0}
        button {display:block}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0],
                style = window.getComputedStyle(button),
                coordinates = button.getBoundingClientRect();

            alert (
                "top = " + coordinates.top +
                "\nleft = " + coordinates.left + 
                "\nwidth = " + style.width + //63px
                "\nheight = " + style.height //24px
            );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="buttonTest" onClick="test()" >Test it!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For me, it returns "8" for left and top. But the `<button>` is inside a `<div>` and there are no paddings or any other offsets, so correct values for top and left should be "0". Or am I wrong?

Comment: Wow, so sorry, @StanE. I'm just seeing this response now (just over a year later, nbd ). The `body` has a margin of 8px applied to it by the user agent. I updated the example to remove some default styling so the expected result will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to compute for `top` and `left` when the element does have a computed `position` set to `static`(that's the default). `top` and `left` are irrelevant in this case.

Comment: OK, but if I used "offsetTop" and "offsetLeft", it would return a proper value. The only problem there is that the offset positions are only relative to the surrounding element. I can't believe there should be no possibility of getting the absolute position of an element, no matter what...

Comment: There is no js-method/property that returns the desired values. You must calculate it on your own. The basic workflow is to sum the offset(Top/Left) of the current element and each [`offsetParent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetParent) of this element. When you use jQuery you may get it via  [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)